# Capture Submit events triggered by Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm using JQuery to submit my form for an excel export. I need to be able to capture that event and do some processing.

**My issue:** The JQuery .submit() event will capture a button with input type="submit", but it will not capture the javascript form.submit();.

**Goal:** Capture any and all form submit events, whether they are submitted by a submit button or javascript form.submit() functions.

To capture the submit event I am using:

```
$("#MainForm").submit(function (event) {
  console.log(this);
  alert("Submitted");
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

**This triggers the above .submit() event:**

```
<input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
```

**This does not trigger the above jquery .submit() event:**

```
$('#XLSExportLink').click(function () {
  var Form = document.getElementById('MainForm');
  AppendHiddenInput(Form, 'Export', 'xlsx', 'XLSXExportInput');
  Form.submit();
  $('#XLSXExportInput').remove();
});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tonyhinkle/dkwsjost/

Comment: Is that what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes basically, buut I need to be able to get the form as a javascript object like "var Form = document.getElementById('MainForm');" because I am doing more processing. I cant just do "$("#MainForm").submit();"

Comment: What is this export link? Is it an anchor tag?

Comment: It happens to be an anchor tag yes, but I am using the form.submit() in JavaScript. See the last function in my question. I need to watch for ALL form submit events. I want to be able to submit how ever we need, so i dont want to change the way we submit. I need a function to watch for ALL submit events.

Answer (score 1):

According to the doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit

> The form's onsubmit event handler (for example, onsubmit="return false;") will not be triggered when invoking this method from Gecko-based applications. In general, it is not guaranteed to be invoked by HTML user agents.

So there is two things you can do

- change the line `Form.submit();` by `$(Form).submit();` which let you do your things on the Form before wrapping it in jQuery.
- or trigger a click event on the `Submit1` button `$('Submit1').click()` and let the event handler do its things.